# Create own struct linked list from Array, but data cannot be borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust, linked-list

I want to convert an array to my own linked list. So Imagine I have the following array:

```
array: ["Manuel", "Antonio", "Elisa"]
```

that I want to convert to a linked list:

```
linked_list: "Manuel" -> "Antonio" -> "Elisa" -> None
```

I created the following code:

```
pub struct Player {
    name: String
}

impl Player {
    pub fn new(name: String) -> Self {
        return Self {name}
    }
}

pub struct PlayerList<'a> {
    player: &'a Player,
    next: Option<&'a PlayerList<'a>>
}

impl<'a> PlayerList<'a> {
    pub fn of(player: &'a Player) -> Self {
        return Self { player, next: None }
    }

    pub fn set_next(&mut self, player_list: &'a PlayerList<'a>) {
        self.next = Some(player_list)
    }
}
```

and the following method to "create" the linked list:

```
let mut head = PlayerList::of(players[0]); // so I create the head based on the first element in the array
for index in 1..players.len() {
    if index == players.len()-1 {
        break;
    }
    let player = players[index];
    let next_player_round = PlayerList::of(player);
    let mut current = &head;
    // here I go to the tail of the linked list and append the next element
    while current.next.is_some() {
        current = current.next.unwrap() 
    }
    current.set_next(&next_player_round); // here I get: `current` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
}
```

But I get:

```
current.set_next(&next_player_round);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `current` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable

consider changing this to be a mutable reference
   |
19 |             let mut current = &mut head;
   |                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is this is a good approach? How do I do this properly?

Comment: _Why_ are you trying to create a LL instead of using `Vec`?

Comment: Is this an academic project to create a linked list in Rust, or is it that you want a data structure that [behaves like a linked list](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html)? If it's the former, look at how the latter implements this.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention it's an academic project to learn, that's why I did not use Linked List (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html)

Comment: [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want a linked list of objects, not references, i.e. the linked list that actually **owns** its contents.

First, I'd make `Player` copyable (manually, using `Clone` trait) to be able to easily deal with initializing the list from a statically-sized array. One can do without that but I wanted to avoid using Vec. Your call to change it later:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Player {
    name: String
}
```

Its constructor should probably take a string slice instead of consuming a `String` but that's not essentially wrong.

Now as for the list:
Rust does not easily allow defining recursive data structures. Similarly to C and C++, a structure in Rust cannot store itself. However, it might store an address of another object of its own type, in C and C++ that would be a pointer (an owning or non-owning one) or reference (non-owning only). In Rust the owning option would be a Box, Rc, or Arc. `Box` having unique ownership is probably the easiest one to reason about.

Now, because Rust does not have a null pointer, that `Box` is wrapped into an `Option`.

```rust
pub struct PlayerNode {
    player: Player,
    next: Option<Box<PlayerNode>>
}
```

As for the `of` and `set_next`:
`of` accepts the `p` argument by immutable reference. Then it copies the storage into the node. Note `&Player` and `clone()`. It could be done with just moves, but for the sake of the example I decided to follow that route.
`set_next` though takes the actual node, wraps it into `Box` (effectively putting it on the heap) and sets the current's node `next` to it. That's the intuitive one.

```rust
impl PlayerNode {
    pub fn of(p: &Player) -> Self {
        return Self { player: p.clone(), next: None }
    }

    pub fn set_next(&mut self, player_list: PlayerNode) {
        self.next = Some(Box::new(player_list))
    }
}
```

Also note, that in several places there are calls to functions `as_ref` and `as_mut`.
These are used because when iterating through the list references are used. However, when accessing "next", I do not want to take ownership of the node (`Option<Node>` type), nor do I want to replace the empty `Option` with something. The desired behaviour is to acquire the reference to the next node provided it's there.
Therefore the usage of `as_ref` which allows to access `Option<T>` as `Option<&T>` (immutable access) or `as_mut` -> `Option<&mut T>` respectively.

Whole code:

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Player {
    name: String
}


impl Player {
    pub fn new(name: String) -> Self {
        return Self {name}
    }
}

pub struct PlayerNode {
    player: Player,
    next: Option<Box<PlayerNode>>
}

impl PlayerNode {
    pub fn of(p: &Player) -> Self {
        return Self { player: p.clone(), next: None }
    }

    pub fn set_next(&mut self, player_list: PlayerNode) {
        self.next = Some(Box::new(player_list))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let players: [Player; 3] = [
        Player::new(String::from_str("Antonio").expect("fatal Anr")),
        Player::new(String::from_str("Roberto").expect("fatal Rob")),
        Player::new(String::from_str("Jose").expect("fatal Jose"))];

    let mut list_head: PlayerNode = PlayerNode::of(&players[0]);
    let mut head = &mut list_head;
    for p in &players[1..] {
        println!("{}", p.name);
        head.set_next(PlayerNode::of(p));
        head = head.next.as_mut().expect("this should not be empty");
    }
    
    let mut head_view = &list_head;
    loop {
        println!("{}", head_view.player.name);
        match head_view.next.as_ref() {
            Some(x) => head_view = x,
            None => break
        };
        
    }
}
```

Live demo: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e1b1ccdd231568041d49b4521bf147bc

There is one problem with that implementation though:
with long enough linked list it might cause stack overflow when going out of scope. Note, that with the first node being destroyed, the next's "destructor" (I'm using C++ terminology here, pardon for that) is going to be called, then from the second one the third one and so on and so forth recursively. Not a big deal for lists of smaller size, but keep in the back of your head, that it's correct by design and unsafe in terms of exceeding the stack size at the same time. For that reason, iterative methods of releasing list nodes are oftentimes utilized.

Comment: what an answer.... awesome

Comment: Note that `String::from_str("...").expect(...)` is better written as `"...".to_owned()`. Also `Person::new` should definitely take a `String`, not `&str`, since it needs a `String`. This avoids copying a string when the user wants the `Person` to take ownership. Same issue with `PlayerNode::of`: if it's just going to clone inside, it should take a `Player` so the user can just `clone` outside, if they need to.

Comment: To be more idiomatic you could also have `PlayerNode::set_next` return a `&mut PlayerNode`, potentially using `Option::insert`. This avoid the `expect` in the next line.